# Connect to ivona.com service using SOAP and Perl

Tags: perl, soap

For a couple of days I am trying to connect to the TTS Ivona (ivona.com) service using SOAP.

Below is the PHP example that works well:

```php
function txtSpeechToFile($txt, $path) {
    $soapURL    = "http://www.ivona.com/saasapiwsdl.php";
    $user       = "some@email.com";
    $pwd        = 'pass';

    $soap       = new SoapClient($soapURL);
    $token      = $soap->__soapCall('getToken', array('email' => $user));

    print gettype($token);

    $speechFile = $soap->__soapCall('createSpeechFile', array(
            'token'         => $token,
            'md5'           => md5(md5($pwd).$token),
            'text'          => $txt,
            'contentType'   => 'text/plain',
            'voiceId'       => 'gb_amy',
            'codecId'       => 'mp3/22050'
        )
    );

    $xx = file_get_contents($speechFile['soundUrl']);

    file_put_contents($path, $xx);
}
```

I am trying to run this in Perl like this:

```perl
use SOAP::Lite;
my $soap = SOAP::Lite->readable(1)->uri($urlPHP)->proxy($soapURL);
my $token = $soap->getToken({('email'=>$user)});
my $speechFile = $soap->createSpeechFile(
    {
        (
            'token'         => '$token',
            'md5'           => md5(md5($pwd) . '$token'),        
            'text'          => $input,      
            'contentType'   => 'text/plain',
            'voiceId'       => 'gb_amy',
            'codecId'       => 'mp3/22050'
        )
    }
);
print $speechFile;
```

I think `$token` is different from PHP's `$token`?

Comment: Provide test credentials for this service so we can study how it works in order to come up with the appropriate SOAP::Lite code. Alternatively, use [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org) to record a working PHP SOAP request/response and provide the log.

Answer (score 2):

1. There's no `md5()` in Perl by default. You must pull it in from [Digest::MD5](http://perldoc.perl.org/Digest/MD5.html):

   ```perl
   use Digest::MD5 qw/ md5 md5_hex /;
   ```

   and later use `md5()` or `md5_hex()`; I believe you will need the latter.
2. I'm not sure about what you need to pass to `$soap->createSpeechFile()`, but if
   it's to be hash reference (equivalent to associative array in PHP), I'd remove
   the extra level of parentheses.

   Or even nicer, define options in advance:

   ```perl
   my $opts = {            # $opts will hold a hash reference
       token       => $token,
       md5         => md5(md5($pwd) . $token),
       text        => $input,
       contentType => 'text/plain',
       voiceId     => 'gb_amy',
       codecId     => 'mp3/22050'
   };
   $soap->createSpeechFile($opts);
   ```

   The same accounts for `$soap->getToken()`.

   Note the sugar: you don't have to use *any* quoting on the left side of `x => "y"`
   construct, **if** it's only one word (`[_1-9a-zA-Z]+`).
3. I guess you don't want to pass the string `$token` (I mean a literal dollar followed by the word token), but
   rather the *contents* of the variable `$token`.  In Perl, single quotes do not interpolate variables, so
   you might want to use double quotes;  however there's no point in writing `"$a"` in Perl,
   you can always use an unquoted `$a`.

   This is already fixed in previous example.